# Why pass in a generic's type when it's already known

Tags: swift, generics, swift4

This question originates from reading the documentation around `NSKeyedUnarchiver` (documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nskeyedunarchiver/2924374-decodedecodable)) and it's instance method below:

```
 func decodeDecodable<T>(_ type: T.Type, forKey key: String) -> T? where T : Decodable
```

What is the purpose of passing in `_ type: T.Type` when the type can already be determined from `T`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swift only allows you to explicitly specify generic parameters on types, not on methods or functions.

```
struct Foo<T> {
    func bar<U>() -> U
}

let foo = Foo<Int>() // legal
foo.bar<Int>() // illegal
```

The language can infer `T` from the return value:

```
let foo = Foo<Int>() // legal
let bar: Int = foo.bar() // legal: T inferred to be Int
```

However, this is not always correct when using polymorphism.

```
class Bar {}
class Baz: Bar {}

let decoded: Bar = decodeDecodable(forKey: "baz")
// would infer decodeDecodable<Bar>(forKey: "baz")
// which is not correct for a Baz object
```